# Twig : Date formatting in "CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]"

Tags: datetime, formatting, twig

I have variable `{{post.updated.date}}` which is originally coming in this format `2016-10-14 07:39:59.000000` but I want to format it like `CCYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]` as per the specification given by [schema.org](https://schema.org/DateTime).

I saw there are filters for this given at [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html) like `{{ post.published_at|date("m/d/Y") }}` but I couldn't find , What I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like charm

`{{ post.published_at|date("c") }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format specified in the PHP date documentation for the twig date filter string:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

I'm not sure based on that format shown in your question exactly what is needed, because I'm not certain what the `CC` part is used for.